# Remove the following redirect chain if possible

Tags: wordpress, performance, .htaccess, redirect, pingdom

I'm trying to improve my website and when i tested my website with pingdom i get this warning at there.

**Remove the following redirect chain if possible:**

http://quoteslab.net/authors/abraham-lincoln

http://quoteslab.net/authors/abraham-lincoln/

This redirection looks harmless but i wanna fix it anyway.
I'm running a wordpress website do you know how can i prevent this kind of redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your htaccess and replacing it with the default WP htaccess file. Any changes?